# How to deploy multitenant Orion without direct MongoDB admin access

Tags: fiware-orion

I am trying to deploy Orion on my own infrastructure, while using an hosted solution for MongoDB. With the hosting plans that I want to use, it is not possible to have access to the admin database.

Is there any way I can achieve multitenancy without access to the admin database?

I would like to have at least three tenants, but I can live with the fact that they must be created outside of Orion.

Answer (score 1):

Current Orion version (0.22.0) uses admin database to authenticate in the case of multitenant. However, a workaround is possible: to set up different contextBroker processes (each one listening in a different port), each one running in mono-tenant way (i.e. without `-multiservice` enabled) with a different `-db`, `-db user` and `-dbpwd`.

Comment: In spite of the above answer, we have added this issue to our development backlog: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/954. If you find it interesting, please add a +1 there. Thanks!

Comment: I find this feature very interesting, because it will simplify a lot the setup.